# "must to be" vs. "must be"

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives

Would you simply show me which one of the following bold parts you would use?

1. Something must **be** taken into account.
2. Something must **to be** taken into account.

Comment: *Must*  must be followed by a main verb in the base form  (so **must be**). I think the only modal verb that is followed by an infinitive (to+V) is *ought*.

Comment: *Must must be followed by a main verb in the base form* but then good to note that *This is a must-to-have gadget if you deal with machines.* is valid!

Comment: @MaulikV You're mixing up *must to have* and *must have*, but your confusion isn't actually relevant to this question, so if you'd like to know more, I suggest you ask about it separately.

Comment: @Laure And *need* and *dare*. Technically, however, when these verbs are used with the *to-* marker they are not acting as modals but as quasi-modals!

Comment: We have to take it into account=We must take it into account=We need to take it into account.

Comment: Have heard of must-have gadgets but never must-to-have gadgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds rather weird to say that "something must to be taken into account". Nor do we find the use of "to" after must in a dictionary or grammar book. The grammar says that we usually use  an infinitive (the basic form of a verb) without to after the auxiliary "must".

So the right sentence is "something must be taken into account.